# Error mesage quickly displaying then hiding as expected in VUE

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a page which I validate the email add `input` `@blur`. This works perfectly and displays the error message if it fails validation rules set but the issue I have is that due to the `@blur`, when I click my reset button the error quickly displays then hides and this is poor UI and I want to stop it but can't figure out how to.

**HTML**

```
<div class="card" v-on:click="select($event)">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label pr-0" for="emailAddField">Email <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input id="emailAddField" ref="pdEmailAdd" class="form-control" type="search" :value="pdEmailAdd" @input="pdEmailAddInput" @blur="emailInputValChecker($event)" placeholder="Enter an email address">
          <div class="input-group-append" :class="emailButtonValidation">
              <a class="btn input-group-text primaryBtn" :class="emailButtonValidation" type="button" :href="'mailto:' + pdEmailAdd">
                  <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
              </a>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div v-if="emailFormatErrorMsg" class="text-danger">Incorrect email address format</div>
  </div>
   <div class="card-footer">
     <button id="resetButton" ref="resetButton" class="btn btn-warning col-4" @click="pdInitPageStates($event)" :disabled="resetDetails">
         Reset details
     </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have 'hacked' at the card trying to use `@click` on the card to get the `id` but this didn't work so I set the `id` in my `data but not happy about it and sure there is a lot better way but I just can't figure it out

**Code**

```
data() {
  return {
    pdEmailAdd: '',
    reg: /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,24}))$/,
    detailsChanged: false,
    emailIncorrectFormat: false,
    targetId: 'resetButton', // HACK
    targetId2: '', // HACK
  }
},

computed: {
  emailButtonValidation() {
      if (!this.pdEmailAdd || !this.reg.test(this.pdEmailAdd)) {
          if (this.pdEmailAdd === '') {
              this.emailIncorrectFormat = false;
          } else {
              this.emailIncorrectFormat = true;
          }

          return 'disabled'
      } else {
           this.emailIncorrectFormat = false;
          return ''
      }
  },
  
  resetDetails() {
      this.detailsChanged = false;

      if (this.pdName != this.$store.state.account.firstname + ' ' + this.$store.state.account.lastname) {
          this.detailsChanged = true;
      }

      if (this.telNoType === 'ddi' && this.pdTelNo != this.$store.state.account.ddi) {
          this.detailsChanged = true;
      } else if (this.telNoType === 'mobile' && this.pdTelNo != this.$store.state.account.mobile) {
          this.detailsChanged = true;
      } else if (this.telNoType === 'na' && this.pdTelNo != '') {
          this.detailsChanged = true;
      }

      if (this.pdExtNo != this.$store.state.account.extension) {
          this.detailsChanged = true;
      }

      if (this.pdEmailAdd != this.$store.state.user.adminemail) {
          this.detailsChanged = true;
      }

      return !this.detailsChanged;
  }
}

// Another hack to try set it soon as page loads
mounted() {
     this.$refs.resetButton.click();
},

methods: {
  emailInputValChecker(event) {
      this.emailFormatErrorMsg = false;

      if (!this.pdEmailAdd || !this.reg.test(this.pdEmailAdd)) {
          if (this.pdEmailAdd === '') {
              this.emailFormatErrorMsg = false;
          } else {
             this.select(event)

             // Uses the 'dirty hacks'
              if (this.targetId !== '' && this.targetId !== 'resetButton' && this.targetId2 !== 'resetButton') {
                  this.emailFormatErrorMsg = true;
              };
          }
      }
  },

  select(event) {
      this.targetId = event.target.id;
      if (this.targetId === 'resetButton') {
          this.targetId2 === 'resetButton';
      } else if (this.targetId === '') {
          this.targetId === 'resetButton';
      }
  }
}
```

Basically all I want is the `input` to check it passes validation when `input` is left unless the reset button is clicked then ignore it but think I've gone code blind and can't think of a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mousedown event on your reset button is what causes blur on the input to fire.  Adding `@mousedown.prevent` to the reset button will stop that from happening specifically when the reset button is clicked.

This snippet ought to illustrate the solution.  Remove `@mousedown.prevent` from the reset button and you'll see similar behavior to your issue, with the error briefly flashing.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    email: '',
    error: null
  },
  methods: {
    onBlur () {
      if (this.email === 'bad') {
        this.error = 'bad email!'
      } else {
        this.error = null
      }
    },
    onReset () {
      this.error = null
      this.email = ''
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="onReset" @mousedown.prevent>Reset</button>
  <p>
    Type in "bad" and leave input to trigger validation error<br>
    <input type="text" v-model="email" @blur="onBlur"/>
  </p>
  <p>{{ email }}</p>
  <p v-if="error">error!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, worked perfectly and aslo lets me remove my 'hack' code